# Merge multiple css rules of a class into a single class declaration?

Tags: css, class, merge, concatenation, stylus

I like it to separate different concerns of a class in css.

Example:

```
// Layout
.myElement {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}

// Chrome
.myElement {
    background: red;
    border: 2px solid green;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px black;
}

// Content
.myElement {
    color: white;
    font-size: 120%;
}

// Interaction
.myElement:hover {
    background: black;
    border: 10px dotted red;
}
```

Pretty fine so far. Personally I find that approach readable, nice to maintain and nice for development. 
But is there any mechanism/tool available which would merge all rules of a class into one single class declaration **before** deployment automatically?

Desired result:

```
.myElement {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: red;
    border: 2px solid green;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 120%;
}

.myElement:hover {
    background: black;
    border: 10px dotted red;
}
```

EDIT:
After reading the comments I felt my "artificial" example wasn't comprehensive enough. Below is a real world example written in the Stylus syntax but the results are the same as described above. I left the original example from above in place.
The next example exists as a single file which describes the appereance of a certain area and its contents which appears in various places on a site. It's like a microcosm for that area. As a consequence you can imagine there are more of these microcosms.

```
// Layout
.events
    padding 2em

.eventItem
    margin 0 0 4em

.eventCal
    float left
    padding 2.5em 0 0

.eventArticle
    margin 0 0 0 6em

.eventHead
    margin 0 0 1em

    time
        margin 0 2em 0 0


// Chrome
.eventCal
    background url("../../assets/img/icon-events.png") no-repeat

.eventHead
    border-bottom .5em solid $chimney


// Content
.eventItem
    list-style-type none

    a
        color $beige
        text-decoration none

    h2
        font-family $elsie

.eventCal
    color $beige
    font-family $elsie
    font-weight bold
    font-size 150%

.eventHead
    font-size 75%

.eventDesc
    font-size 90%


// Interaction
.eventItem    
    a:hover
            color $chimney
            text-decoration underline
```

Comment: You can always use those comments INSIDE the class you know.

Comment: is there any reason you can't just write the css code the way it's written in your desired result in the first place? you could just include the comments inside that single class...

Comment: *Readable and nice to maintain*.. As for me, merged version is much more comprehensible.

Comment: I think the idea is that he has lots of these that he wants to merge and wants a tool that will do it for him versus having to do it himself.  I would also assume that each of these elements aren't nearby each other as they are now and are actually separated by other elements which fall under their respective categories.  

To that end...  I don't know of a tool would do this other than the skills and expertise of a human being.

Comment: @DavidStarkey Yes I know ;)

Comment: After reading the comments I have to admit the example is not comprehensive enough. I'll rewrite my post. AND I better should have written "Personally I find it readable and nice to maintain." ;)

Comment: @Michael You are quite right whith your assumptions! The point I'm asking is I was pretty sure I have seen such a tool. First I thought it was CSSComb, but it isn't.

Comment: Why cant you just copy paste? or if your css file is very big just make your own simple C/C++ /javascript or any other programming language you may know program. Such a program wouldnt take more than 20-30 mins to code

Comment: It's worth mentioning that as a project were to scale, reordering your selectors would make specificity issues really hard to debug and find a solutions.

Answer (score 0):

My computer is sorta nagging me to reboot after a few straight days of coding , but basically I do stuff like that fairly regularly in my libraries. Basically what you can do to quickly mimmick this functionality is to grab one of the zillion coding examples for enumerating the CSSrules from the sheets.

Then in the enumeration function simply take the selectorText property and drop it into document.querySelector/querySelectorAll which will give you the elements matching the selectorText toss these , the selectorText and related cssText into a little {}/[] or whatever suits your fancy.

After the enumeration finishes do a document.createElement('style') and use the insertRule() to  glue the styles together as you please.

Then simply grab the finished product from style.textContent and you have your merged stylesheet.

Being as the commonly available code for enumeration does the actual hard part , this is a nice lazy evenings coding task for most folks and it will do the job EXACTLY the way YOU want.